# Using orderBy filter dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to enter ordering criteria from input box and order the content dynamically. The code works fine as it is, but when I try to change:

```
orderBy:'age'
```

with

```
orderBy:'{{criteria}}'
```

it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
<p>Enter ordering criteria in the input box:</p>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="criteria"></p>
<p>{{criteria}}</p>
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'age'">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends =
      [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
       {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{}}` is only for interpolation in non angular expressions. Since ng-repeat is executed against the `scope`, you can just reference the variable directly.

`orderBy:criteria`

Comment: Here's a jsbin with your example: https://jsbin.com/jevorudula/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are wanting to filter your list with the text box and order the result by the age property of each object? If you wish to do this, you'd just chain filters.

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'age' | filter : criteria">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a plunker with an example of using multiple filters
http://plnkr.co/edit/8rfitXitGhjjthUXujOL?p=info